# How to skip/seek ahead quickly with ffmpeg on remote file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I am reading in several remote video files using ffmpeg and saving short clips of them. For example, if I want to take a 5 second clip of an hour long video at the 30 minute mark, I would create a command like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1800 -i "http://example.com/example.mp4" -ss 0 -t 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```

This works fine and dandy but it takes FOREVER because it seems to simply start downloading at the beginning and finishes when it gets to the point that I want.

How can I make ffmpeg (or perhaps another utility?) skip ahead to the point in the video that I want rather than streaming through the entire thing? I assume it is possible since flash video players are able to do this.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/300567/is-there-a-way-to-make-ffmpeg-seek-faster-to-an-end-of-file-on-a-network-share?rq=1

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but that question doesn't have any answers and it's very old too.

Comment: It's related, so I'm linking it.  I'd actually mark it as a possible duplicate, but I can't since it has no answers.

Answer (score 0):

The command you posted does work correctly and efficiently with remote videos (e.g. from youtube). Perhaps newer `ffmpeg` is more capable, or the server you tried did not support seeking with HTTP range requests.

A working example, using `youtube-dl`:

```
video=`youtube-dl -g eRsGyueVLvQ -f best`
ffmpeg -ss 438 -i "$video" -ss 0 -t 5 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mp4
```